# How can I dynamically register DbSets into DbContext and add a row to the table?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

I have too many entities and registering everyone of them is giving me a headache not to mention the load to instantiate the DbContext.
I tried to dynamically register the dbsets.

To dynamically register DbSet s into DbContext I used the article in this link:

[how to dynamically register entities dbcontext](https://blog.christian-schou.dk/how-to-dynamically-register-entities-dbcontext/)

I added an extension as a file:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterAllEntities<BaseModel>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
                                            .Where(c => c.IsClass && 
                                                        !c.IsAbstract && 
                                                        c.IsPublic &&
                                                        typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(c));

        foreach (Type type in types)
            modelBuilder.Entity(type);
    }
}
```

I made an abstract class called BaseEntity that all my entities implemented.

Inside the `ApplicationDbContext`, I overrode the `OnModelCreating` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var entitiesAssemblyInt = typeof(BaseEntity<int>).Assembly;
    var entitiesAssemblyGuid = typeof(BaseEntity<Guid>).Assembly;

    modelBuilder.RegisterAllEntities<BaseEntity<int>>(entitiesAssemblyInt);
    modelBuilder.RegisterAllEntities<BaseEntity<Guid>>(entitiesAssemblyGuid);
}
```

It works perfectly in migrations but when I want to use the `DbContext` in my `CommandHandler` to add a row to my table named client I don't know how to call client from context.

```
context.Client.Add(client);
```

This doesn't work because I didn't register the `DbSet`s directly into `DbContext` and there is no client in the context.

Comment: You can't add properties to a class at runtime. Use `context.Set<Client>()`.

Comment: Not an answer: I would not recommend if this is production code for maintainability and possibility of future bugs.  This would fail our code review process from our senior developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is generally a bad idea*, for maintainability, debugging, readability reasons... The list goes on.

However, if you must, you can use `_context.Set<Donation>()` to fetch the DbSet for a given entity.

**Example**

The following code with a correctly registered DbSet & Context.

**This is the
recommended way**

```
    public async Task<Donation?> GetDonationAsync(Guid donationID)
    {
        return await _context.Donations
            .Where(x => x.ID == donationID)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddDonationAsync(Donation donation)
    {
        await _context.Donations.AddAsync(donation);
    }
```

Is the same as doing:

```
    public async Task<Donation?> GetDonationAsync(Guid donationID)
    {
        return await _context.Set<Donation>()
            .Where(x => x.ID == donationID)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddDonationAsync(Donation donation)
    {
        await _context.Set<Donation>().AddAsync(donation);
    }
```

The above code is contained in my repository services. I would recommend doing it this way and calling your repository, rather than directly calling your db context.

**Example**

Repository example

```
public class DonationRepository : IDonationRepository
{
    private readonly MyDatabaseContext _context;

    public DonationRepository(MyDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public async Task<Donation?> GetDonationAsync(Guid donationID)
    {
        return await _context.Donations
            .Where(x => x.ID == donationID)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddDonationAsync(Donation donation)
    {
        await _context.Donations.AddAsync(donation);
    }

}
```

Controller example

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DonationController : Controller
{

    private readonly IDonationRepository _donationRepository;

    private readonly ILogger<DonationController> _logger;

    public DonationController(ILogger<DonationController> logger,
                            IDonationRepository donationRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _donationRepository = donationRepository;
        
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDonationValue")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDonationValueAsync(Guid donationID)
    {

        var donation = await _donationRepository.GetDonationAsync(donationID);
        
        // Doesn't exist!
        if (donation == null) {
            _logger.LogError($"Couldn't find Donation with ID: '{donationID}'.");
            return NotFound();
        }
        
        _logger.LogInformation($"Found Donation with value of: '{donation.Amount}'.");          
        return Ok(donation.Amount);


    }

}
```